# About using the lagrange multiplier.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Today I have seen a question like the following;

$x+y+z=5$ and $xy+yz+xz=3$ and $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$

What is the maximum value $x$ can get?

Now it is pretty obvious that question is solvable using many simple elementary methods like say $(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)=25$

$25=x^2+y^2+z^2+6 \rightarrow x^2+y^2+z^2=19$

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz $(y^2+z^2)(1+1)\geq (z+y)^2$

$2(19-x^2)\ge(5-x)^2$

$x_{max}=\dfrac{13}{3}$

However I would also like to solve it by the lagrange multiplier, here are my efforts

$f(x,y,z,k)=x+5-(y+z)+k(x+y+z-5)$

$f_k'=0$

$f_x'=k+1$

$f_y'=k-1$

$f_z'=k-1$

$k=1,-1$ and $x$ goes nowhere near $\dfrac{13}{3}$

> So my question is where am I wrong and how can I fix it?
>
> Besides are there maxima minima questions that can't be solved with lagrange,
> is this one of them?

Comment: You are maximizing x subject to two constraints so $f=x + k_1(x+y+z-5)+k_2(xy+yz+xz-3)$ however this does not take into account the inequality constraints that $x,y,z$ are all positive.

Comment: So to find the positive lagrange isn't the right method to use here?

Comment: You can try and if $x,y,z$ all turn out to be positive then you are OK. However I suspect they won't.

Comment: Thank you for the help:)

Comment: I was wrong. Lagrange multipliers do give you positive answers. But in general inequality constraints are a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Lagrange multiplier**s**, you could write
$$F=x+\lambda(x+y+z-5)+\mu(xy+yz+xz-3)$$
Computing derivatives 
$$F'_x=1+\lambda +\mu  (y+z)\tag 1$$
$$F'_y=\lambda +\mu  (x+z)\tag 2$$
$$F'_z=\lambda +\mu  (x+y)\tag 3$$
$$F'_\lambda= x+y+z-5\tag 4$$
$$F'_\mu=xy+yz+xz-3\tag 5$$

Now, set all of them equal to $0$ and, solving, you will find two solutions, one for the minimum and the other for the maximum.

Comment: About solving these derivatives. Do we say that all derivatives are equal to each other or is it sth else? Because in many questions assuming all are equal gives the solution. I am asking this because I am not well accustomed to lagrange, thank you:)

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın. Each of them is $=0$. From$(2)$ and $(3)$, you see that $y=z$, just continue.

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın. You are welcome !

Answer (score 2):

Your function $f(x,y,z,k)=x+5-(y+z)+k(x+y+z-5)$ is not the right function fot Lagrange. The right function is given by

$f(x,y,z,k)=x+5-(y+z)+k(xy+yz+xz-3)$:

Comment: I didn't understand one point why did we use the second equality?

Comment: You are maximizing $x$ subject to two constraints !!

Comment: I see now. Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

We will use the quadratic equation approach to determine the min and max values of $x$. We have: $y+z = 5-x$, and $yz + x(y+z) = 3\implies 3- x(5-x)= yz\implies x^2-5x+3= yz\le \dfrac{(y+z)^2}{4}= \dfrac{(5-x)^2}{4}\implies 4x^2-20x+12 \le 25-10x+x^2\implies 3x^2-10x-13 \le 0 \implies (3x -13)(x + 1)\le 0\implies -1 \le x \le \dfrac{13}{3}\implies x_{\text{min}} = -1, x _{\text{max}} = \dfrac{13}{3}$ .

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed to mindlessly apply Lagrange's method to such a problem, for the following reason: The problem defines a more or less complicated global situation, whereas Lagrange's method just produces a few points that might be interesting in the context. But these points can only feel what happens in a tiny neighborhood of them. In the case at hand the constraints define a feasible set $F$ which is the intersection of a plane and a hyperboloid, hence $F$ could a priori extend to infinity, and  the objective function $x\restriction F$ could be unbounded. In addition there is the constraint that all variables should be positive, hence it could very well be that we only have a $\sup$, which is taken when $y\to0+$, $z\to 0+$, etcetera.

You already have found out that all feasible points are lying on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=19$, hence  $F$ lies on the intersection of this sphere with the plane $x+y+z=5$, i.e., on a compact circle $C$. This ensures that we have a $\max x\restriction C$, and this $\max$ would be brought to the fore by Lagrange's method. We are lucky: The method produces exactly two points $p$, $q\in C$ (see @ClaudeLeibovici 's answer). Then one of these has to be the $\max$ of $x\restriction C$ and the other the $\min$ of $x\restriction C$. Now we are lucky again: The max-point $p$ also fulfills the positivity condition (one has to check this!), hence $p$ is a fortiori the maximum for $x\restriction F$. (If  $p$ had violated the positivity condition additional investigations would have been necessary.)